# Formatting Dynamic textfieldtype.DYNAMIC in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, format, textfield, flash-cs6

Hi I am trying to format a textfield called myResult with the following code. It seems to have no effect on the size or type of text when I attempt it. Is there another way to format the textfield or am I missing something. The textfieldtype is DYNAMIC as it is displaying a result. Here is the code I am using

```
var myFormatA:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 

myFormatA.color = 0xAA0000;    
myFormatA.size = 28;    
myFormatA.italic = true;     
myFormatA.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;

myResult.setTextFormat(myFormatA);
```

Comment: You should also set myResult.defaultTextFormat = myFormat, imho.

Comment: It is a possible answer. The new text will need the defaultTextFormat to be set. You have't really explained how it works (or not) right now.

Answer (score 0):

use defaultTextFormat to apply a default format to any text that will be displayed (in the future if you will) in your textfield. Use setTextFormat to format the text that is currently displayed in your textfield. This is an important difference.